# c# Windows Form, replace string in textbox (file content) with another string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, file, windows-forms-designer

I have a textbox that contains all of the lines of a loaded file.
It looks like this:

[image]

I am able to load a specific line of the file that contains a specific string using this in the app:

[image]

How would I be able to update the file/main textbox after I press the "Edit Module" button, if any of the textboxes would be changed .

For example, I would change Exam Weighting: "0.4" to Exam Weighting: "0.6", then press the "Edit Module" button which would edit the main textbox(file content). Which then would allow me to save the file with the updated content.

This is the code I am using to get a specific line from the file based on string from a textbox:

```
    private void editModuleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        citation = editModuleComboBox.Text;

        citationChange();
    }

    private void citationChange()
    {
        List<string> matchedList = new List<string>();

        string[] linesArr = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

        //find matches
        foreach (string s in linesArr)
        {
            if (s.Contains(citation))
            {
                matchedList.Add(s); //matched
            }
        }

        //output
        foreach (string s in matchedList)
        {
            string citationLine = s;
            string[] lineData = citationLine.Split(',');
            selectedModuleLabel.Text = lineData[2];
            moduleTitleTextBox.Text = lineData[3];
            creditsTextBox.Text = lineData[4];
            semesterTextBox.Text = lineData[5];
            examWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[6];
            examMarkTextBox.Text = lineData[7];
            testWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[8];
            testMarkTextBox.Text = lineData[9];
            courseworkWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[10];
            courseworkMarkTexbox.Text = lineData[11];
        }
    }
```

If somebody with enough rep could insert the images to this post, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Firstly, how do you populate the textboxes on the right if you are reading text file or are you populating only the first or last line always? Personally I would make a custom class with all the entries like module, credits, semester etc and read the text file, store the values in a List of Custom Class and then populate the values in ListView (rather than Textbox on the left) and if user clicks item in ListView, I can know the index of the row clicked and I can edit that item in the listview. It will be trivial to save the updated list to a new text file.

Comment: This is a very strange way to track data being edited.  But if you *need* to replace a specific line in the multi-line text box with serialized data from your other controls then you're going to need to track which line needs replacing.  Then you'd essentially replace the entire string with itself, swapping out that line likely in a loop.  It would probably be easier to not track your data as one big text blob but instead as a collection of in-memory objects.  Then the inputs can just update properties on the current object.

Comment: I populate the textboxes on the right using the code I provided in the question, it reads all lines, then whatever is chosen in the ComboBox, it uses that string to search for it in the file, returns the whole line, and populates the textboxes. Also, I already have a class containing credits etc. Like this: https://paste.ofcode.org/ 

And this is how the app works (populates the texboxes): https://i.gyazo.com/5c032f5c3fba468486b39ca8f2033a44.mp4

Comment: It's pretty messy, if using a ListView would be better and easier. I will definitely do it to not confuse myself so much @ErAcube.

Comment: This is first time that I'm working with a file, where you read, edit, save it, etc. So it's probably a huge mess :Z

Comment: @Dr4ken hey if you haven't figured any method yet, try my solution

Comment: @Nobody hey, I am using it right now. I'll let you know how it goes, thanks a lot :)

Comment: So did it work out? if yes,  do you require any further help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution might not be the perfect, but should work for you. What you need to do is whenever the *Edit Module* button is pressed, create a new string based on the text fields and replace it with the original line. First declare a string variable `private string ChangedString = "";` inside the class, then:

```
    foreach (string s in matchedList)
    {
        string citationLine = s;
        string[] lineData = citationLine.Split(',');
        string Stream = lineData[0]; //Store this somewhere so that it can be accessed later
        string Stage = lineData[1]; //Store this somewhere so that it can be accessed later
        selectedModuleLabel.Text = lineData[2];
        moduleTitleTextBox.Text = lineData[3];
        creditsTextBox.Text = lineData[4];
        semesterTextBox.Text = lineData[5];
        examWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[6];
        examMarkTextBox.Text = lineData[7];
        testWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[8];
        testMarkTextBox.Text = lineData[9];
        courseworkWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[10];
        courseworkMarkTexbox.Text = lineData[11];
    }
```

store `Stream` and `Stage` in any Textbox/ComboBox if you already haven't then replace them accordingly in the following line. Now in `EditButton_Click` [Click Event] write:

```
ChangedString  = Stream + "," + Stage + "," + selectedModuleLabel.Text + "," + moduleTitleTextBox.Text
                + "," + creditsTextBox.Text + "," + semesterTextBox.Text + "," +  examWeightingTextBox.Text + "," 
                + examMarkTextBox.Text + "," + courseworkWeightingTextBox.Text + "," + courseworkMarkTexbox.Text;
```

Now replace this string with the original line.

Edit: As you would get the line number which is being edited, store it in a variable, let's say

```
int LineBeingEdited = 3 //Supposing line number three is being edited.
```

Then again in the same Click event you can write this:

```
ChangedString  = Stream + "," + Stage + "," + selectedModuleLabel.Text + "," + moduleTitleTextBox.Text
                + "," + creditsTextBox.Text + "," + semesterTextBox.Text + "," +  examWeightingTextBox.Text + "," 
                + examMarkTextBox.Text + "," + courseworkWeightingTextBox.Text + "," + courseworkMarkTexbox.Text;

var lines = TextBox1.Lines;
lines[LineBeingEdited] = ChangedString;
TextBox1.Lines = lines;
```

EDIT 2: To get the line number I would suggest you to modify your `for each` loop to `for` loop. Also add a `int` variable to store the line number inside the class like : `private int LineBeingEdited = 0;`

Modify this `for each` :

```
foreach (string s in linesArr)
    {
        if (s.Contains(citation))
        {
            matchedList.Add(s); //matched
        }
    }
```

To `for` loop:

```
for (int a = 0; a < linesArr.Length; a++)
     {
        if (s.Contains(citation))
        {
           matchedList.Add(linesArr[a]); //matched
           LineBeingEdited = a;
           break; //breaks the loop when a match is found
        }
     }
```

The above method is being used, taking into consideration that there will always be a **single match**. `LineBeingEdited` will now have the line number and can be accessed from anywhere in the class

Comment: Okay, this works perfectly. I can edit and save the file, then re-open it, and have things be changed. How do I get the line number that is selected? So that the 'lineBeingEdited' would change?

Comment: in `if (s.Contains(citation))
            {
                matchedList.Add(s); 
            }` I hope `matchedList` always gets ony one line right?

Comment: I think so, (it's not directly my code, I tweaked it a little), but I'm pretty sure it only stores the line that is being used, since it only shows that line as a string.
EDIT: It stores the line that matches the string of "citation", I'm pretty sure

Comment: @Dr4ken Hey, I've updated my answer to fetch the line number. if this worked well in your case, please do accept my answer. Would help me with my repo points :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update of your answer, unfortunately, with your for loop I get this error:
"the name 's' does not exist in the current context".
It's referring to the `foreach (string s in linesArr)` since it had the `string s` inside of the foreach, however in the for loop it's not there.

Comment: Okay nvm, I managed to get it working (I'm starting to understand how you can change how code works within different loops by putting things the `if` statements. I got it working like this: 
EDIT: I'm not gonna bother posting the code in the comments, it looks awful xd
But thank you so much, you managed to help me in a huge way!!!